# Why are new packages been installed after using command Update-Package --reinstall

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have a solution in which there are few nuget packages.

Those packages were referencing to different net frameworks. eg. few were targeting net451, some were targeting net452 and some were targeting net461.

My project had net461 framework. So i used the command `Update-Package --reinstall` to reinstall the packages targeting net461 framework.

That went successful, But i am not sure why there are more packages been added then i already had?

**Before Updating my Packages.**

```
<package id="EnterpriseLibrary.Common" version="6.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling" version="6.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.Caching" version="6.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.Configuration" version="6.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.Data" version="6.0.1304.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.ServiceBus" version="6.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.WindowsAzure.Storage" version="6.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tools" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Dynamic.Runtime" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Queryable" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Net.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Net.Requests" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.ObjectModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Text.RegularExpressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Timer" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="8.1.1" targetFramework="net452" />
```

**After Updating my Packages**

```
<package id="EnterpriseLibrary.Common" version="6.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling" version="6.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.Caching" version="6.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.Configuration" version="6.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.Data" version="6.0.1304.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.ServiceBus" version="6.0.1304.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.WindowsAzure.Storage" version="6.0.1304.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.AppContext" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Collections" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Collections.Concurrent" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Console" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Debug" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tools" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Diagnostics.Tracing" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Dynamic.Runtime" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Globalization" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Globalization.Calendars" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IO.Compression.ZipFile" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Expressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Queryable" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Net.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Net.Requests" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Net.Sockets" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.ObjectModel" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Reflection" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Reflection.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Resources.ResourceManager" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Handles" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.Numerics" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Text.RegularExpressions" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Tasks" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Threading.Timer" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Xml.ReaderWriter" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Xml.XDocument" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="8.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Which new packages were being added and were these added to both the packages.config and .csproj files or just the .csproj file?  Assuming that this is for a C# project.

Comment: I have added my packages. so you can have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But i am not sure why there are more packages been added then i already had?

This is NuGet default behavior. When we install the nuget package to the project, nuget will also add its dependencies to the project.

**The reason** why there are more packages been added is that **dependencies are different when their targeting different framework**. Some of packages will introduce more dependencies to project when you targeting `.net461`. So there are more packages been added then you already had.

For example, you can check Denpendencies for the package `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, `System.Net.Http` and `System.Runtime.InteropServices`:

[image]

[image]

Obviously, those packages will add some new dependencies to the project when you used the command `Update-Package -reinstall` to reinstall the packages targeting net461 framework.

Hope this helps.